# Sparql query with AVG clause

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology

I need to write a **sparql 1.1** query on a small ontology in the recording industry. The request is to find the **average** of the artists connected to each album. Below, the ontology written in N-triple format:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX ex: <http://esempio.org/#>
PREFIX : <http://prova.org/#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
:artist1 rdf:type :Artist .
:artist2 rdf:type :Artist .
:artist3 rdf:type :Artist .
:artist4 rdf:type :Artist .
:artist5 rdf:type :Artist .
:album1 rdf:type :Album .
:album2 rdf:type :Album .
:album1 :include :artist1 .
:album1 :include :artist2 .
:album1 :include :artist3 .
:album2 :include :artist1 .
:album2 :include :artist2 .
:album2 :include :artist3 .
:album2 :include :artist4 .
:album2 :include :artist5 .
```

I tryed this qyery, but it don't seems correct...

```
Select AVG(?NumeroA) as ?media
WHERE {
Select ?album , count(*) as ?NumeroA
Where {
?album rdf:type :Album,
  :include ?artista.
?artista rdf:type :Artista.
}
group by ?album
}
```

...does anybody know how to fix (or rewrite...) it?

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem correct" mean? Are you getting an error? If so, what's the error? You can [edit] your question to add clarification.

Comment: it would be cool if the SPARQL query posted here is the same as executed ... just saying because this is clearly illegal syntax, neither can you use a comma `,` after `:Album` not a comma between projection variables. Also in the data shown here it's called `:Artist` and in the query `:Artista`

Comment: so, for people trying to run the query ,please use this one: `prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> PREFIX : <http://prova.org/#>  Select (AVG(?NumeroA) as ?media) WHERE { Select ?album  (count(*) as ?NumeroA) Where { ?album rdf:type :Album;   :include ?artista. ?artista rdf:type :Artist. } group by ?album }` - which by the way returns `4.0` with Apache Jena which makes since with `:album1` having 3 and `:album2` 5 artists respectivly

Comment: Yes, the error is known to me. I have to write:
?album rdf:type :Album;
          :include ?artista.

My question is: the syntax of my query is correct or Not? I Want the average for all Albums. I expected the number 4 as result

Comment: the query that I posted does return `4.0` - I don't understand what else you're asking now